# XSD cached within Websphere?

Tags: caching, xsd, websphere, war

I've got an XSD file within a web applcation thats running on my server - I've hotfixed this, however my changes are not being reflected when I use my web application.

I believe its being cached somewhere, however, I've cleared the caches I can find, restarted IIS on the server, restarted my server through the command prompt (stopServer.bat & startServer.bat)

These caches I've found & cleared:

- ibm\websphere\appserver\profiles\app server profile\temp\node\app
  server
- ibm\websphere\appserver\profiles\app server profile\wstemp
- ibm\websphere\appserver\profiles\app server
  profile\tranlog\cell\node\app server
- ibm\websphere\appserver\profiles\app server profile\logs\app server
- ibm\websphere\appserver\profiles\app server profile\logs\ffdc

My changes are not being reflected - its not picking it up, as I've updated the version number within my XSD to 4, yet it always shows 3. I've found every instance of the xsd within the harddrive and they're all up-to-date. (Bad I know to update old kept instances but its frying my skull)

Am I missing anything else? Pulling my hair out here!

Comment: Can you further elaborate on this comment: "I've hotfixed this"? Where did you place your updated file? Also, what version of WAS are you running and is this a clustered environment or a standalone server?

Comment: Its been resolved - found another file had been hotfixed.

Comment: for what its worth - "i've hotfixed this" - referred to the xsd document within the application. it appeared (as was unaware of the other editing) that the fixes werent taking effect as the versioning hadnt increased. WAS 6.1 on a standalone - although largely irrelevant now, thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other files had been edited on the server

Comment: You should edit your question and add any additional information instead writing an answer.

Comment: i thought it best to mark it as answered so those filtering for unanswered questions dont land in it :)